# how to get index value of checked Item list dialog in android

Tags: if-statement, dialog, android-listview, boolean

I am using dialog checkbox list. now i want to get the index value of the checked item so that i can make a specific boolean value set to true. actually i am new to android so if i an asking something silly so i am sorry for that

```
      private void repeat(){
    AlertDialog.Builder ab=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ab.setTitle("Repeat Alarm");
    ab.setMultiChoiceItems(days, null, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(arg2){
                //chk_monday=true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ss", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
```